# What causes an object's formula field to become unavailable in reports?

Tags: reporting

I have a situation where formula fields become unavailable to me when I create a report, and I'm not sure why. Here is the scenario:

When I try to create a:

1. report on Accounts -- Formula Fields are **available**.
2. report on Accounts with *CustomObject1* -- Formula fields are **available**
3. report on Accounts with *CustomObject1* with *CustomObject2* - Formula fields are ***unavailable***.

*CustomObject1* is the Detail side of Master-Detail with Accounts. 
*CustomObject2* is the Detail side of Master-Detail with *CustomObject2*

*CustomObject2* is also a detail side of a Master-Detail with *Contacts*.

All formula fields do appear on at least one page layout, and I am an Administrator.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a report that includes fields from Accounts, Custom1, Custom2 **and** Contacts. Since there are no scenarios that present all four objects, I created formula columns on Custom2 that pull the values I need from Contacts. Those columns are not available for the report... and also no formula fields from Accounts are visible either.

I've been unable to locate a document that explains why this is the case

Comment: check field level security once for those fields

Comment: Is Accounts with Custom1 with Custom2 a Custom Report Type?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor - Not that I'm aware of. It appears as a choice under Accounts & Contacts section when I click new report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess that your first two reports are standard report types so they automatically update with all the fields. The last report type sounds like a custom one where you have to manually add the fields to the report type.

Here's the help article on [how to add fields to your custom report type](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Except the fields aren't available in the field chooser to actually add them. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Custom Report Types can be in the standard report type category folders. Check [this Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_manage_report_type.htm&language=en_US) and see if the _Accounts with CustomObject1 with CustomObject2_ report type is listed under Custom Report types. If so, see [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&language=en_US) for help on getting those fields on your reports.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Ah! That's it. That help page was exactly what I was looking for -- but unable to find on my own. I needed to specifically go into the custom report types and add the missing fields.